# Angular Directive -- Can't access child or grandchild nodes in a tree view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that builds a tree view.  It's based off of a code example at http://jsfiddle.net/KNM4q/113/.  I would like to be able to click on any node in the tree, and have the click execute a method in a controller that processes data particular to that node.  While I have gotten the code working in the root node and the child nodes I can't make it work with grandchildren or great granchildren nodes.

Here is the plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/AKiD8ZyKK8dUSPEcWI3p?p=preview.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">

  <tree val="treeData" zo="itemDetail(param)"  ></tree>

</div>
```

Here is the directive:

```
angular.module('components')
    .directive('tree', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        terminal: true,
        scope: { val: '=', parentData:'=', zo:'&' },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var template = '<span>{{val.text}}</span><button  ng-click="showDetail()"  ng-show="val.text">Show Detail</button> ';
            if (angular.isArray(scope.val.items)) {
                template += '<ul class="indent"><li ng-repeat="item in val.items"><tree val="item" parent-data="val.items" zo=zo({param:item.text})   >  </tree></li></ul>';
            }
            scope.showDetail = function(index) { 
                var param = 'aaa';
                scope.zo(); 

            };
            var newElement = angular.element(template);
            $compile(newElement)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(newElement);            
        }


    }
});
```

Here is the controller:

```
function appCtrl($scope) {
    var treeData = {
        "text": "root",
        "items": [{
            "text": "Furniture",
                "items": [{
                "text": "Tables & Chairs"
            }, {
                "text": "Sofas",
                    "items": [{
                    "text": "Tables & Chairs"
                }, {
                    "text": "Sofas"
                }]
            }, {
                "text": "Occasional Furniture"
            }]
        }, {
            "text": "Decor",
                "items": [{
                "text": "Bed Linen"
            }, {
                "text": "Curtains & Blinds"
            }, {
                "text": "Carpets"
            }]
        }]
    };

    //initial parameter that is sent
    $scope.param = 'root';

    $scope.treeData = treeData;

    $scope.itemDetail = function (param){
        alert('in controller ' + param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass the function as an object reference and 2 way bind it back to each parent level using `=` not `&` in directive scope.

HTML

```
<!-- notice removed "()" -->
<tree val="treeData" zo="itemDetail"  ></tree>
```

JS

Since `zo` is bound to parent scope function, can use it in template html

```
.directive('tree', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        terminal: true,
        scope: { val: '=', parentData:'=', zo:'=' },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var template = '<span>{{val.text}}</span><button  ng-click="zo(val.text)"  ng-show="val.text">Show Detail</button> ';
            if (angular.isArray(scope.val.items)) {
                template += '<ul class="indent"><li ng-repeat="item in val.items"><tree val="item" parent-data="val.items" zo="zo"   >  </tree></li></ul>';
            }

            var newElement = angular.element(template);
            $compile(newElement)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(newElement);            
        }


    }
```

In simpler terms this is the same as doing:

```
function foo( param ){
   alert(param);
}

var bar = foo;

bar('someString') // alerts "someString"
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GoOAuDEMRIQ5LQEyam8y?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Ok.  So in effect you ended passing the controller function as an object to the directive which then allows the directive to work with it?  It looks like to get it working you changed three lines:

Comment: Here's another solution which is less clean.  But probably easier for beginning angular users to understand: http://jsfiddle.net/lfernandez55/vFTdv/

Comment: Your "in simpler terms" elaboration/explanation rocks.  I wish the docs on scope explained passing functions this clearly.